# JS - оператор continue не работает

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, такой код является некорректным ?

Когда я добавляю - "continue jump" - код перестает работать:

```
 const elem = document.getElementsByClassName("my_class");
 let text_error; 
 if(elem == undefined)
 {
 text_error = "undefined"; 
 alert(text_error); 
 }
 const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Теперь добавляю - "continue jump"

```
 const elem = document.getElementsByClassName("my_class");
 let text_error; 
 if(elem == undefined)
 {
 text_error = "undefined"; 
 alert(text_error); 
 continue jump;
 }
 const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

 jump:
 alert("jump");
```

И все - теперь ничего не работает.

continue - нельзя так использовать ?

Comment: Дубликат: [JS - оператор continue](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1433724/js-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-continue)

Comment: Его можно использовать только в циклах `while` и `for`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в целом метки нежелательно использовать, они приводят к спагетти коду.
просто так ты переместиться не можешь, нужен цикл, типа

```
let itemsPassed = 0;
let i, j;

top:
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < tests.length; j++) {
    if (!tests[j].pass(items[i])) {
      continue top;
    }
  }

  itemsPassed++;
}
```

либо когда ты перемещаешься в какой-то блок, но это работает только с break

```
foo: {
  console.log('привет');
  break foo;
  console.log('эта строка не будет исполнена');
}
console.log('мир');

// Вывод:
//   "привет"
//   "мир"
```

подробнее https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label